# How to migrate data from an associated table's column to an hstore column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I'm working on a project where localisation was done by creating associated `*_locales` tables with a `locale` and `name` field. I am migrating this over to use an `hstore`  column (using Postgres) but I don't quite have the syntax right.

The structure is now like this

```
table: thingy_locales
  locale :string
  name   :string
  thingy_id : integer


table: thingies
  name_translations :hstore
```

In a migration I wish to move all data from the `thingy_locales` table into the `name_translations` field with an key of `'en'` (as currently there are only 'en' locales in the `thingy_locales` table.)

so I've tried this

```
execute "UPDATE thingies t SET name_translations=(select (\"'en'\" => \"'|name|'\")::hstore from thingy_locales where thingy_id = t.id);"
```

but that gives me

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "'en'" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ort_categories loc SET name_translations=(select ("'en'" => ...
                                                             ^
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it to work.

```
execute "UPDATE thingies t SET name_translations=hstore('en', (select name from thingy_locales where thingy_id = t.id));"
```

does the job perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an automatic SQL command to do it, but you probably want to do multiple migrations:

- Add the hstore column to `thingies`
- Iterate over all of the `thingy_locales`, reading them into a hash/hashes. Then do `Thingy.create!(name_translations: {'en' => hash})`
- Drop `thingy_locales`

Migrations in Rails can have any arbitrary code in them. Since this is an instance where you will be transforming the data, doing it in Ruby is probably your safest bet.

If speed is a concern, then you may need to go for an optimized SQL query, but frankly if you aren't worried about speed, don't trouble yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad idea.  I'll see what some PostGres genius comes up with tho as there is, in my case, a metric wet shitload of data so speed is important.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just looking at your code again, assuming that you have this association:

```
class Thingy
  has_many :thingy_locales
end

class ThingyLocale
  belongs_to :thingy
end
```

it seems like what you want to do something like this:

```
Thingy.all.each do |thingy|
  name = thingy.thingy_locales.where(locale: 'en').first.select(:name)
  thingy.name_translations = {'en' => name}
  thingy.save!
end
```

Comment: Yep - that should work. (I just made a minor mod as in the `Locale` model the `locale`:`name` pairing is unique)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to grind a ton of data through Ruby, do it inside the database. Two approaches immediately come to mind:

1. Use a correlated subquery in an UPDATE:

   ```
   connection.execute(%q{
     update thingies
     set name_translations = (
       select hstore(array_agg(locale), array_agg(name))
       from thingy_locales
       where thingy_id = thingies.id
     )
   })
   ```
2. JOIN to a derived table in an UPDATE:

   ```
   connection.execute(%q{
     update thingies
     set name_translations = dt.h
     from (
       select hstore(array_agg(locale), array_agg(name)) as h, thingy_id
       from thingy_locales
       group by thingy_id
     ) as dt
     where id = dt.thingy_id
   })
   ```

The core of both is to use the [`hstore(text[], text[])` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) to build the `hstore` and the [`array_agg` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to build the key and value arrays that `hstore(text[], text[])` wants.

Don't be afraid to throw SQL into `connection.execute` calls in your migrations. Pretending that your database is too dumb to do anything interesting may be ideologically pure in a Rails application but it is a non-productive and unprofessional attitude. You'll be better served in the long run by learning SQL and how your databases work.

Comment: Totally agree with you mu-is-too-short I was just going for a quick n' dirty hack, but if the dataset is large enough, it's always better to drop down to SQL.